# How to detect Edge running in IE mode?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to detect when a user is browsing Edge in IEMode (IE11).
I have tried checking for the user agent, the document mode and browser hints.
Using this methods results in them detecting as not Edge.

Is there anyway to know that the real browser is Edge?

User agent:

```
if((userAgent.indexOf("edg/")!= -1) || (userAgent.indexOf("edge/")!= -1)) { 
   // this is Microsoft Edge
   window.alert('Microsoft Edge');
}
```

Document mode:

```
if (!document.documentMode && window.msWriteProfilerMark) {
   // this is Microsoft Edge
   window.alert('Microsoft Edge');
}
```

Browser hints:

```
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);
var isEdgeChromium = isChrome && (userAgent.indexOf("edg/")!= -1) || (userAgent.indexOf("edge/")!= -1);

if (isEdgeChromium){
   // this is Microsoft Edge
   window.alert('Microsoft Edge');
}
```

Comment: Don’t use the user agent. Use feature detection instead

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Edge IE mode tabs actually running Internet Explorer, which is why Microsoft Edge is a two-engine(`Trident` and `Chromium`) browser, where IE11 engine is required to enable Edge IE mode.

For more details, you could refer to this IE FAQ: [Internet Explorer 11desktop app retirement FAQ](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549).